# SQL Query with condition - Count new and returning values for each ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

So here is the problem that I've been trying to solve without success for the last couple of days: I have a table which keeps track of the participation of people (identified by their unique PartcipantId) to some events (identified by their unique EventId).

I would like to write a SQL query (I'm using MS Access 2010) which returns for each event the number of returning participants (ie which have already participated in another event with a lower EventId), the number of new participants (first time they appear, if sorting by EventId) and the total number of participants for that event?

As as example:

```
ParticipantId | EventId
1               1
1               3
1               4
2               3
2               4
3               5
```

Would give:

```
EventId | New | Returning | Total
1         1     0           1
3         1     1           2
4         0     2           2
5         1     0           1
```

Is this even possible to begin with? Any idea on how I could do it?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery to determine the first event for a user.  Then, Access' `iif` allows you to count only first events for the `New` column:

```
select  e.eventid
,       sum(iif(e.eventid = p.FirstEvent,1,0)) as [New]
,       sum(iif(e.eventid <> p.FirstEvent,1,0)) as Returning
,       count(p.participantid) as Total
from    (
        select  participantid
        ,       min(eventid) as FirstEvent
        from    Table1
        group by
                participantid
        ) as p
left join
        Table1 e
on      p.participantid = e.participantid
group by
        e.eventid
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did perfectly the trick!
Being new to Access, I would probably have resorted to do the count in code using many more simpler queries, but your solution is much more elegant and efficient!!